# Azure Pipeline : Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Here is my yaml:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/WebApplication1.sln'
  project: '**/WebApplication1.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  name: 'NuGetToolInstaller'
  displayName: 'NuGet tool installer'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '${solution}'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '518d385e-cce7-4d9b-a805-fd5ec2b4f108'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '${solution}'
    arguments: '--configuration ${BuildConfiguration}'
```

When the pipeline runs, I get a warning

> Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

Here is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: Try this: project: WebApplication/WebApplication/**/*WebApplication1.csproj 
Solution: WebApplication/WebApplication/**/*WebApplication1.sln

Comment: I modified like this variables:
  solution: 'WebApplication1/WebApplication1/**/*WebApplication1.sln'
  project: 'WebApplication1/WebApplication1/**/*WebApplication1.csproj'
but I still get the same warning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I replaced with yaml with this and now it's working like a charm

```
# ASP.NET

# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- main

variables:
  solutionDir: 'WebApplication1'
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'


steps:
- script: pwd

- script: ls -a

- script: dotnet build
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  workingDirectory: '$(solutionDir)'

- script: cd $(solutionDir) | ls

- script: dotnet test
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  workingDirectory: '$(solutionDir)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    workingDirectory: '$(solutionDir)'
    
- script: dotnet publish -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
  workingDirectory: '$(solutionDir)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```